# Hi How Can I use a foreach on an IEnumerable<> lists?

Tags: ienumerable

```
public IEnumerable<int> Merge(IEnumerable<int> first, IEnumerable<int> second)
{

}
```

Comment: I want to merge them..

Comment: I would recommend specifying what language you are working with. Perhaps this is Java? https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_foreach_loop.asp Also, look at some formatting for Markdown that StackOverflow uses: https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2015/06/giving-better-answers-on-stack-overflow.html

Comment: merging two lists in java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java#:~:text=Not%20simpler%2C%20but%20without%20resizing%20overhead%3A

Answer (score 0):

If both argument is (actually) `List<T>`, you can *append* one to another:

```cs
public List<int> AppendInPlace(List<int> first, List<int> second)
{
    first.AddRange(second);

    return first;
}
```

If your intention is *chaining* two IEnumerators, you can follow [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/526157/14900042).